Why systems evolves 90 degrees to gradient of Hamiltonian but not 270 degrees?
Since Hamiltonian is the total energy it is understandable that a particle in phase space evolves perpendicular to gradient of Hamiltonian where dot product of two vectors is zero hence there is no energy lost or gained. But what is the reason system evolves in one direction that energy is conserved ($90$ degree rotation), and not the other direction ($270$ degree or $-90$ degree rotation) that energy is also conserved?
So why not $\frac{dq}{dt} = -\frac{dH}{dp}$ and $\frac{dp}{dt}=\frac{dH}{dq}$?

Look, things in physics are imbued with meaning, and it is not just mathematical games that you can just pick different conventions. We have chosen to consider momentum $p=mv=m\frac{\mathrm dq}{\mathrm dt}$ and so it will be ridiculous if your momentum is positive yet the velocity is negative.
